# Problem in reference

Tags: bibliographies, errors

When I compile my `.tex` file, a text `aaaa` appears at the beginning of my reference page.

[image]

Here are the packages I am using:

```
    \documentclass[article,12pt,oneside,a4paper,english,brazil,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}        
% Pacotes usados
\usepackage{times}%Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Codificacao do documento
\usepackage{indentfirst}%Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{nomencl}%Lista de simbolos
\usepackage{color}%Controle das cores%
\usepackage{graphicx}%Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}%Para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{lipsum}%Para geração de dummy text
\usepackage[abnt-emphasize=bf,abnt-and-type=e,alf]{abntex2cite}%Citações ABNT
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Usado pela Ficha catalográfica
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    % Paginas com as citações na bibl
%\usepackage[num,overcite]{abntex2cite} % Citações padrão ABNT
%\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

% Configuracoes do documento
\graphicspath{{./Figuras/}}%Images na pasta "Figuras"
\setsecheadstyle{\bfseries \normalsize \uppercase}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize \uppercase}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries \normalsize}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}%Margens esquerda-direita
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}%Margens cima-baixo
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}%paragrafo
\OnehalfSpacing%espacamento de 1,5
\setlength{\ABNTEXcitacaorecuo}{4cm}%recuo citacao direta +3

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{brazil} % Seleciona o idioma do documento
\frenchspacing % Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.



\section{Introdu\c c\~ao}
\label{secIntroducao}
\normalsize
% TEXTO DA INTRODUCAO
A boa gestão de um empreendimento se tornou indispensável em um mercado cada vez mais competitivo, e a necessidade de gerenciar um projeto de forma integrada, onde o Gerente de Projetos, tem uma visão completa do prazo e custo do empreendimento e do seu cenário futuro fez com que a EVS se tornasse ferramenta de gestão indispensável nos escritórios e canteiros de obras por todo o Brasil. \cite{Kerzner2011}



\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{bibliograph}

\end{document}
```

### `.bib` file

```
@article{pmbok2013,
  title={Um guia do conhecimento em gerenciamento de projetos},
  author={PMBOK, GUIDE},
  journal={Quarta Edi{\c{c}}{\~a}o},
  year={2013}
}

@article{kerzner2011,
  title={Gerenciamento de projetos: uma abordagem sist{\^e}mica para planejamento, programa{\c{c}}{\~a}o e controle},
  author={Kerzner, Harold},
  journal={S{\~a}o Paulo: Bl{\"u}cher},
  year={2011}
}

@book{mattos2010,
  title={Planejamento e controle de obras},
  author={Mattos, Aldo D{\'o}rea},
  year={2010},
  journal={S{\~a}o Paulo, Brasil},
  publisher={Pini}
}

@book{vargas2013,
  title={An{\'a}lise de Valor Agregado: Revolucionando o gerenciamento de prazos e custos, 6ed.},
  author={Vargas, Ricardo},
  year={2013},
  ed={6},
  journal={Sexta Edi{\c{c}}{\~a}o},
  publisher={Brasport}
  }

@article{rovai2002,
  title={Avalia{\c{c}}{\~a}o de performance de projetos atrav{\'e}s do earned value management system},
  author={Rovai, Ricardo Leonardo and TOLEDO, Nilton Nunes},
  journal={ENCONTRO NACIONAL DE ENGENHARIA DE PRODU{\c{C}}{\~A}O, XXII},
  year={2002}
}

@article{navon2005,
  title={Automated project performance control of construction projects},
  author={Navon, Ronie},
  journal={Automation in construction},
  volume={14},
  number={4},
  pages={467--476},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{flemingkoppelman2000,
  title={Koppelman (2000)},
  author={Fleming, QW},
  journal={Earned Value Project Management}
}

@article{fleming2002,
  title={Earned value management},
  author={Fleming, Quentin W and Koppelman, Joel M},
  journal={Cost Engineering},
  volume={44},
  year={2002}
}

@MastersThesis{couri2006,
author = {Guilherme Adib Couri},
title = {Gerenciamento de projetos pela análise do valor
agregado para otimização de escopo, prazos e custos},
school = {Universidade Federal Fluminense},
year = {2006},
OPTaddress = {Niteroi},
}
@article{mattos2006,
  title={Como preparar or{\c{c}}amentos de obras, 2d.},
  author={Mattos, Aldo D{\'o}rea},
  journal={S{\~a}o Paulo, PINI},
  year={2006}
}

@article{rabechini2011,
  title={Fundamentos em Gest{\~a}o de Projetos-Construindo Compet{\^e}ncias para Gerenciar Projetos. 3ed},
  author={RABECHINI JR, Roque and Carvalho, MM},
  journal={S{\~a}o Paulo, Brasil},
  year={2011}
}
@inproceedings{terrel1998,
  title={Evaluating project performance tools--A case study},
  author={Terrel, MS and Brock, AW and Wise, JR},
  booktitle={29th Annual Project Management Institute Seminars and Symposium, Long Beach, CA},
  year={1998}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called a minimal working example with bibliography [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: Since your code snippet contains no `\cite` instructions and no corresponding bibliographic entries, it's quite impossible to offer a diagnosis, let alone a cure.

Comment: I tested and discover that `\bibliographystyle{apalike2}` causes the problem. Maybe some conflict with some `abnt` package. If you comment `%\bibliographystyle{apalike2}` and compose, run `bibtex` and compose again, it is fine.

Comment: I found some mention to `a` in `FUNCTION {forward.pass}` from `apalike2.bst`.

Comment: I think the problem comes from `\usepackage[abnt-emphasize=bf,abnt-and-type=e,alf]{abntex2cite}%Citações ABNT` and `\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT` you are using. However the manual of this package is not in English and I cannot help. You could remove these lines and use `\usepackage{natbib}` instead. Everything works then.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few inconsistencies in your document. The one causing an issue with you bibliography is that you have conflicting citation styles. The package `abntex2cite` automatically sets a bibliography style through its options. Therefore, you should not call `\bibliographystyle` in your document. You have then two options, either remove the aforementioned command from your document (which will keep the ABNT citation style) or remove the package `abntex2cite` from the preamble, by doing either of those the document renders perfectly.

**Extra tips**

1. Since you loaded `inputenc` and `fontenc` you no longer need to use commands for the special characters like `\c c` for `ç`, you can write them directly in the code;
2. You are also loading twice the following packages: `indentfirst`, `abntex2cite` and `graphicx`;
3. The way you are changing the section headings style is not applied properly (if you check the document the bibliography name is rendered with Sans-Serif font whilist the other sections use Roman font). If you take a quick look in the class manual `abntex2` you will see how it is intented for the user to change the styles: for font type it is through renewing the command `\ABNTEXchapterfont` and for font size `\ABNTEXchapterfontsize`. The class also has the options `section=TITLE` and `chapter=TITLE` to have uppercased chapter and section headings.